# Inserção de dados em db sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, aplicação-web, razor

Estou tendo problemas em conectar o meu projeto a o banco de dados, não entendo o motivo, já olhei vários tutoriais, uso o sql server 2017, consigo acessar a db em uma aplicação, mas no site não está funcionando.[image: imagem do erro]

estou usando o seguinte código

web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SicConnectionString" connectionString ="Data Source=ETID-012312\\ETID012312;User=sa;Password=admin2312;Initial Catalog=Sic_db;Integrated Security=True;" providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

cadastro.cshtml
    @{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Cadastro";

```
var fantasia = "";
var cnpj = "";
var cep = "";
var endereco = "";
var estado = "";
var cidade = "";
var bairro = "";
var celular = "";
var telefone = "";
var email = "";
var usuario = "";
var senha = "";
var csenha = "";
var error = false;
var resultado = "";

if (IsPost)
{
    var db = Database.OpenConnectionString("Data Source=;User=;Password=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True;");
    fantasia = Request.Form["fantasia_txv"];
    cnpj = Request.Form["cnpj_txv"];
    cep = Request.Form["cep_txv"];
    endereco = Request.Form["endereco_txv"];
    estado = Request.Form["estado_txv"];
    cidade = Request.Form["cidade_txv"];
    bairro = Request.Form["bairro_txv"];
    celular = Request.Form["celular_txv"];
    telefone = Request.Form["telefone_txv"];
    email = Request.Form["email_txv"];
    usuario = Request.Form["usuario_txv"];
    senha = Request.Form["senha_txv"];
    csenha = Request.Form["csenha_txv"];

    // Define the insert query. The values to assign to the
    // columns in the Product table are defined as parameters
    // with the VALUES keyword.

        var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO dbo.TempAcc (TA_fantasia, TA_cnpj, TA_cep, TA_endereco, TA_estado, TA_cidade, TA_bairro, TA_celular, TA_telefone, TA_email, TA_usuario, TA_senha)" +
            "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11)";
        db.Execute(insertQuery, fantasia, cnpj, cep, endereco, estado, cidade, bairro, celular, telefone, email, usuario, senha);
        // Display the page that lists products.

}
```

}

alguém pode me dizer aonde estou errando? ou um modelo a seguir que funcione? os tutoriais da ms não resultaram bem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na sua string de conexão

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="SicConnectionString" connectionString ="Data Source=ETID-012312\\ETID012312;User=sa;Password=admin2312;Initial Catalog=Sic_db;Integrated Security=True;" providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Substitua o atributo "User" por "User ID"

Comment: Eu fiz essa tentativa, logo depois o erro atual sumiu, mas um novo apareceu, Erro de instancia, nenhuma outra informação.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, procurei uma string que se adequa-se a meu código, e assim como você citou o "user" deveria ter sido trocado por "user id", e como ainda esta em desenvolvimento e uso uma instancia local, o "user id" e "password" não precisam ser declarados, meu código funciona agora, óbrigado.

Comment: Não é que eles não precisam ser declarados, nesse caso você está autenticando através de seu login no windows e não no SQL Server.

Comment: isso mesmo, eu estou aprendendo sobre ainda, por isso minha confusão.